# How to compile Apache Arrow Flight C++ example in Windows-10 (VS 2019)

Tags: c++, cmake, apache-arrow, cmake-modules

I downloaded the Apache Arrow Flight sample code from git (https://github.com/apache/arrow) and I was able to build the cpp example (using CMake and VS2019). I could not build the example "minimal_build" because it gives CMake missing library errors.
The package-links given in cmake files are incorrect. When I change them individually then that package compiles and the next-one breaks.

### Command Line Output :

```
D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build>SET CMAKE_MODULE_PATH=D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\cmake_modules

D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build>SET Arrow_DIR=D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\build\release\Release

D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build>run_static.bat

D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build>if exist "arrow-build" rd arrow-build /s /q

D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build>if exist "dist" rd dist /s /q

D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build>if exist "example" rd example /s /q

D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build>echo
ECHO is on.

D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build>echo "=="
"=="

D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build>echo "== Building Arrow C++ library"
"== Building Arrow C++ library"

D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build>echo "=="
"=="

D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build>echo
ECHO is on.

D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build>set INSTALL_PREFIX=D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build\dist

D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build>mkdir arrow-build

D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build>pushd arrow-build

D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build\arrow-build>cmake ..\..\..     -GNinja     -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build\dist     -DARROW_DEPENDENCY_SOURCE=BUNDLED     -DARROW_BUILD_SHARED=OFF     -DARROW_BUILD_STATIC=ON     -DARROW_COMPUTE=ON     -DARROW_CSV=ON     -DARROW_DATASET=ON     -DARROW_FILESYSTEM=ON     -DARROW_HDFS=ON     -DARROW_JSON=ON     -DARROW_MIMALLOC=ON     -DARROW_ORC=ON     -DARROW_PARQUET=ON     -DARROW_PLASMA=ON     -DARROW_WITH_BROTLI=ON     -DARROW_WITH_BZ2=OFF     -DARROW_WITH_LZ4=ON     -DARROW_WITH_SNAPPY=ON     -DARROW_WITH_ZLIB=ON     -DARROW_WITH_ZSTD=ON
-- Building using CMake version: 3.20.0-rc3
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 11.0.0 with GNU-like command-line
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 11.0.0 with GNU-like command-line
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/VC/Tools/Llvm/bin/clang.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/VC/Tools/Llvm/bin/clang++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Arrow version: 4.0.0 (full: '4.0.0-SNAPSHOT')
-- Arrow SO version: 400 (full: 400.0.0)
-- clang-tidy not found
-- clang-format not found
-- Could NOT find ClangTools (missing: CLANG_FORMAT_BIN CLANG_TIDY_BIN)
-- infer not found
-- Found Python3: C:/Users/amishra2/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe (found version "3.9.1") found components: Interpreter 
-- Found cpplint executable at D:/Git/Arrow-Master/cpp/build-support/cpplint.py
-- System processor: AMD64
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_SSE4_2
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_SSE4_2 - Success
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_AVX2
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_AVX2 - Success
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_AVX512
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_AVX512 - Success
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_BIG_OBJ
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_BIG_OBJ - Success
-- Arrow build warning level: PRODUCTION
Configured for RELEASE build (set with cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE={release,debug,...})
-- Build Type: RELEASE
-- Using BUNDLED approach to find dependencies
-- ARROW_ABSL_BUILD_VERSION: 0f3bb466b868b523cf1dc9b2aaaed65c77b28862
-- ARROW_AWSSDK_BUILD_VERSION: 1.8.133

**** more and more logs **** 

-- ARROW_ZSTD_BUILD_VERSION: v1.4.8
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - not found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Looking for __SIZEOF_INT128__
-- Looking for __SIZEOF_INT128__ - not found
-- Boost include dir: D:/Git/Arrow-Master/cpp/examples/minimal_build/arrow-build/boost_ep-prefix/src/boost_ep
-- Boost libraries: boost_system_static;boost_filesystem_static
-- Building snappy from source
-- Building brotli from source
-- Building without OpenSSL support. Minimum OpenSSL version 1.0.2 required.
-- Building gflags from source
-- Added static library dependency gflags_static: D:/Git/Arrow-Master/cpp/examples/minimal_build/arrow-build/gflags_ep-prefix/src/gflags_ep/lib/libgflags.a
Building Apache Thrift from source
-- Building (vendored) mimalloc from source
-- Building RapidJSON from source
-- Building xsimd from source
-- Building ZLIB from source
-- Building lz4 from source
-- Building zstd from source
-- Building RE2 from source
-- Building utf8proc from source
-- Found hdfs.h at: D:/Git/Arrow-Master/cpp/thirdparty/hadoop/include/hdfs.h
-- All bundled static libraries: Snappy::snappy;Brotli::brotlicommon;Brotli::brotlienc;Brotli::brotlidec;gflags_static;thrift::thrift;mimalloc::mimalloc;ZLIB::ZLIB;LZ4::lz4;zstd::libzstd;re2::re2;utf8proc::utf8proc
-- CMAKE_C_FLAGS:  -Qunused-arguments -O3 -DNDEBUG  -Wa,-mbig-obj -Wall -Wno-unknown-warning-option -Wno-pass-failed -msse4.2
-- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:   -Qunused-arguments -fcolor-diagnostics -O3 -DNDEBUG  -Wa,-mbig-obj -Wall -Wno-unknown-warning-option -Wno-pass-failed -msse4.2
-- Looking for backtrace
-- Looking for backtrace - not found
-- Could NOT find Backtrace (missing: Backtrace_LIBRARY Backtrace_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Creating bundled static library target arrow_bundled_dependencies at D:/Git/Arrow-Master/cpp/examples/minimal_build/arrow-build/release/arrow_bundled_dependencies.lib
-- -------------
-- Arrow version:                                 4.0.0-SNAPSHOT
--
-- Build configuration summary:
--   Generator: Ninja
--   Build type: RELEASE
--   Source directory: D:/Git/Arrow-Master/cpp
--   Install prefix: D:/Git/Arrow-Master/cpp/examples/minimal_build/dist
--
-- Compile and link options:
--
--   ARROW_CXXFLAGS="" [default=""]
--       Compiler flags to append when compiling Arrow
--   ARROW_BUILD_STATIC=ON [default=ON]
--       Build static libraries
--   ARROW_BUILD_SHARED=OFF [default=ON]
--       Build shared libraries
--   ARROW_PACKAGE_KIND="" [default=""]
--       Arbitrary string that identifies the kind of package
--       (for informational purposes)
--   ARROW_GIT_ID=178c7ddbfa015e2418df8c6729a16cad0bf24b9b [default=""]
--       The Arrow git commit id (if any)

**** more and more logs **** 

-- Project component options:
--
--   ARROW_BUILD_UTILITIES=OFF [default=OFF]
--       Build Arrow commandline utilities
--   ARROW_COMPUTE=ON [default=OFF]
--       Build the Arrow Compute Modules
--   ARROW_CSV=ON [default=OFF]
--       Build the Arrow CSV Parser Module
--   ARROW_CUDA=OFF [default=OFF]
--       Build the Arrow CUDA extensions (requires CUDA toolkit)
--   ARROW_DATASET=ON [default=OFF]
--       Build the Arrow Dataset Modules
--   ARROW_FILESYSTEM=ON [default=OFF]
--       Build the Arrow Filesystem Layer
--   ARROW_FLIGHT=OFF [default=OFF]
--       Build the Arrow Flight RPC System (requires GRPC, Protocol Buffers)
--   ARROW_GANDIVA=OFF [default=OFF]
--       Build the Gandiva libraries
--   ARROW_HDFS=ON [default=OFF]
--       Build the Arrow HDFS bridge
--   ARROW_HIVESERVER2=OFF [default=OFF]
--       Build the HiveServer2 client and Arrow adapter
--   ARROW_IPC=ON [default=ON]
--       Build the Arrow IPC extensions
--   ARROW_JEMALLOC=OFF [default=OFF]
--       Build the Arrow jemalloc-based allocator
--   ARROW_JNI=OFF [default=OFF]
--       Build the Arrow JNI lib
--   ARROW_JSON=ON [default=OFF]
--       Build Arrow with JSON support (requires RapidJSON)
--   ARROW_MIMALLOC=ON [default=OFF]
--       Build the Arrow mimalloc-based allocator
--   ARROW_PARQUET=ON [default=OFF]
--       Build the Parquet libraries
--   ARROW_ORC=OFF [default=OFF]
--       Build the Arrow ORC adapter
--   ARROW_PLASMA=ON [default=OFF]
--       Build the plasma object store along with Arrow
--   ARROW_PLASMA_JAVA_CLIENT=OFF [default=OFF]
--       Build the plasma object store java client
--   ARROW_PYTHON=OFF [default=OFF]
--       Build the Arrow CPython extensions
--   ARROW_S3=OFF [default=OFF]
--       Build Arrow with S3 support (requires the AWS SDK for C++)
--   ARROW_TENSORFLOW=OFF [default=OFF]
--       Build Arrow with TensorFlow support enabled
--   ARROW_TESTING=OFF [default=OFF]
--       Build the Arrow testing libraries
--
-- Thirdparty toolchain options:
--
--   ARROW_DEPENDENCY_SOURCE=BUNDLED [default=AUTO|BUNDLED|SYSTEM|CONDA|VCPKG|BREW]
--       Method to use for acquiring arrow's build dependencies
--   ARROW_VERBOSE_THIRDPARTY_BUILD=OFF [default=OFF]
--       Show output from ExternalProjects rather than just logging to files
--   ARROW_DEPENDENCY_USE_SHARED=ON [default=ON]
--       Link to shared libraries
--   ARROW_BOOST_USE_SHARED=ON [default=ON]
--       Rely on boost shared libraries where relevant
--   ARROW_BROTLI_USE_SHARED=ON [default=ON]
--       Rely on Brotli shared libraries where relevant
--   ARROW_BZ2_USE_SHARED=ON [default=ON]
--       Rely on Bz2 shared libraries where relevant
--   ARROW_GFLAGS_USE_SHARED=ON [default=ON]
--       Rely on GFlags shared libraries where relevant
--   ARROW_GRPC_USE_SHARED=ON [default=ON]
--       Rely on gRPC shared libraries where relevant
--   ARROW_LZ4_USE_SHARED=ON [default=ON]
--       Rely on lz4 shared libraries where relevant
--   ARROW_OPENSSL_USE_SHARED=ON [default=ON]
--       Rely on OpenSSL shared libraries where relevant
--   ARROW_PROTOBUF_USE_SHARED=ON [default=ON]
--       Rely on Protocol Buffers shared libraries where relevant
--   ARROW_THRIFT_USE_SHARED=OFF [default=OFF]
--       Rely on thrift shared libraries where relevant
--   ARROW_UTF8PROC_USE_SHARED=ON [default=ON]
--       Rely on utf8proc shared libraries where relevant
--   ARROW_SNAPPY_USE_SHARED=ON [default=ON]
--       Rely on snappy shared libraries where relevant
--   ARROW_UTF8PROC_USE_SHARED=ON [default=ON]
--       Rely on utf8proc shared libraries where relevant
--   ARROW_ZSTD_USE_SHARED=ON [default=ON]
--       Rely on zstd shared libraries where relevant
--   ARROW_USE_GLOG=OFF [default=OFF]
--       Build libraries with glog support for pluggable logging
--   ARROW_WITH_BACKTRACE=ON [default=ON]
--       Build with backtrace support
--   ARROW_WITH_BROTLI=ON [default=OFF]
--       Build with Brotli compression
--   ARROW_WITH_BZ2=OFF [default=OFF]
--       Build with BZ2 compression
--   ARROW_WITH_LZ4=ON [default=OFF]
--       Build with lz4 compression
--   ARROW_WITH_SNAPPY=ON [default=OFF]
--       Build with Snappy compression
--   ARROW_WITH_ZLIB=ON [default=OFF]
--       Build with zlib compression
--   ARROW_WITH_ZSTD=ON [default=OFF]
--       Build with zstd compression
--   ARROW_WITH_UTF8PROC=ON [default=ON]
--       Build with support for Unicode properties using the utf8proc library
--       (only used if ARROW_COMPUTE is ON)
--   ARROW_WITH_RE2=ON [default=ON]
--       Build with support for regular expressions using the re2 library
--       (only used if ARROW_COMPUTE or ARROW_GANDIVA is ON)
--
-- MSVC options:
--
--   MSVC_LINK_VERBOSE=OFF [default=OFF]
--       Pass verbose linking options when linking libraries and executables
--   BROTLI_MSVC_STATIC_LIB_SUFFIX=-static [default="-static"]
--       Brotli static lib suffix used on Windows with MSVC
--   PROTOBUF_MSVC_STATIC_LIB_SUFFIX="" [default=""]
--       Protobuf static lib suffix used on Windows with MSVC
--   RE2_MSVC_STATIC_LIB_SUFFIX=_static [default="_static"]
--       re2 static lib suffix used on Windows with MSVC
--   SNAPPY_MSVC_STATIC_LIB_SUFFIX="" [default=""]
--       Snappy static lib suffix used on Windows with MSVC
--   LZ4_MSVC_STATIC_LIB_SUFFIX=_static [default="_static"]
--       Lz4 static lib suffix used on Windows with MSVC
--   ZSTD_MSVC_STATIC_LIB_SUFFIX=_static [default="_static"]
--       ZStd static lib suffix used on Windows with MSVC
--   ARROW_USE_STATIC_CRT=OFF [default=OFF]
--       Build Arrow with statically linked CRT
--
-- Parquet options:
--
--   PARQUET_MINIMAL_DEPENDENCY=OFF [default=OFF]
--       Depend only on Thirdparty headers to build libparquet.
--       Always OFF if building binaries
--   PARQUET_BUILD_EXECUTABLES=OFF [default=OFF]
--       Build the Parquet executable CLI tools. Requires static libraries to be built.
--   PARQUET_BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF [default=OFF]
--       Build the Parquet examples. Requires static libraries to be built.
--   PARQUET_REQUIRE_ENCRYPTION=OFF [default=OFF]
--       Build support for encryption. Fail if OpenSSL is not found
--
-- Gandiva options:
--
--   ARROW_GANDIVA_JAVA=OFF [default=OFF]
--       Build the Gandiva JNI wrappers
--   ARROW_GANDIVA_STATIC_LIBSTDCPP=OFF [default=OFF]
--       Include -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc when linking with
--       Gandiva static libraries
--   ARROW_GANDIVA_PC_CXX_FLAGS="" [default=""]
--       Compiler flags to append when pre-compiling Gandiva operations
--
-- Advanced developer options:
--
--   ARROW_EXTRA_ERROR_CONTEXT=OFF [default=OFF]
--       Compile with extra error context (line numbers, code)
--   ARROW_OPTIONAL_INSTALL=OFF [default=OFF]
--       If enabled install ONLY targets that have already been built. Please be
--       advised that if this is enabled 'install' will fail silently on components
--       that have not been built
--   Outputting build configuration summary to D:/Git/Arrow-Master/cpp/examples/minimal_build/arrow-build/cmake_summary.json
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/Git/Arrow-Master/cpp/examples/minimal_build/arrow-build

D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build\arrow-build>ninja install
[20/335] Performing build step for 'lz4_ep'
FAILED: lz4_ep-prefix/src/lz4_ep-stamp/lz4_ep-build lz4_ep-prefix/src/lz4_ep/lib/liblz4.a
cmd.exe /C "cd /D D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build\arrow-build\lz4_ep-prefix\src\lz4_ep && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -P D:/Git/Arrow-Master/cpp/examples/minimal_build/arrow-build/lz4_ep-prefix/tmp/lz4_ep-build-RELEASE.cmake && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E touch D:/Git/Arrow-Master/cpp/examples/minimal_build/arrow-build/lz4_ep-prefix/src/lz4_ep-stamp/lz4_ep-build"
CMake Error at D:/Git/Arrow-Master/cpp/examples/minimal_build/arrow-build/lz4_ep-prefix/tmp/lz4_ep-build-RELEASE.cmake:37 (message):
  Command failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

   'D:/Git/Arrow-Master/cpp/build-support/build-lz4-lib.sh' 'AR=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/VC/Tools/Llvm/bin/llvm-ar.exe' 'OS=Windows'

  See also

    D:/Git/Arrow-Master/cpp/examples/minimal_build/arrow-build/lz4_ep-prefix/src/lz4_ep-stamp/lz4_ep-build-*.log


-- stdout output is:

-- stderr output is:

CMake Error at D:/Git/Arrow-Master/cpp/examples/minimal_build/arrow-build/lz4_ep-prefix/tmp/lz4_ep-build-RELEASE.cmake:47 (message):
  Stopping after outputting logs.


[26/335] Performing download step (download, verify and extract) for 'mimalloc_ep'
-- Downloading...
   dst='D:/Git/Arrow-Master/cpp/examples/minimal_build/arrow-build/mimalloc_ep-prefix/src/v1.6.4.tar.gz'
   timeout='none'
   inactivity timeout='none'
-- Using src='https://github.com/microsoft/mimalloc/archive/v1.6.4.tar.gz'
-- [download 100% complete]
-- Downloading... done
-- extracting...
     src='D:/Git/Arrow-Master/cpp/examples/minimal_build/arrow-build/mimalloc_ep-prefix/src/v1.6.4.tar.gz'
     dst='D:/Git/Arrow-Master/cpp/examples/minimal_build/arrow-build/mimalloc_ep-prefix/src/mimalloc_ep'
-- extracting... [tar xfz]
-- extracting... [analysis]
-- extracting... [rename]
-- extracting... [clean up]
-- extracting... done
[31/335] Performing download step (download, verify and extract) for 'boost_ep'
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build\arrow-build>popd

D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build>echo
ECHO is on.

D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build>echo "=="
"=="

D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build>echo "== Building example project using Arrow C++ library"
"== Building example project using Arrow C++ library"

D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build>echo "=="
"=="

D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build>echo
ECHO is on.

D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build>mkdir example

D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build>pushd example

D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build\example>cmake ..       -GNinja       -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build\dist"       -DARROW_LINK_SHARED=OFF
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 11.0.0 with GNU-like command-line
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 11.0.0 with GNU-like command-line
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/VC/Tools/Llvm/bin/clang.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/VC/Tools/Llvm/bin/clang++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:24 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindArrow.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Arrow", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Arrow" with any of
  the following names:

    ArrowConfig.cmake
    arrow-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Arrow" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Arrow_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Arrow"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/Git/Arrow-Master/cpp/examples/minimal_build/example/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build\example>ninja
ninja: error: loading 'build.ninja': The system cannot find the file specified.


D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build\example>popd

D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build>echo
ECHO is on.

D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build>echo "=="
"=="

D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build>echo "== Running example project"
"== Running example project"

D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build>echo "=="
"=="

D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build>echo
ECHO is on.

D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build>call example\arrow_example.exe
'example\arrow_example.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

D:\Git\Arrow-Master\cpp\examples\minimal_build>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

See the details on the [Developing on Windows](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/developers/cpp/windows.html) docs page. In particular, see the
**System Setup** section, which shows this command you'll need to run first to set up VS 2019:

```sh
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" -arch=amd64
```

Try running that before running `run_static.bat`.